# Конец списка?

Tags: android

Скачиваю данные с сервера небольшими партиями (скачиваю JSON objects). Апи необходимое на сервере есть.

Вопрос - как не зная общего количества JSON objects задать что-то типа "пока есть что скачивать" - скачать очередную партию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (response != null) {
 loadData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Заведи булеву переменную (допустим isLastLoadNull = false)
Когда получишь от сервера пустой JSON, положи в эту переменную true.

Проверяй переменную перед очередной загрузкой данных с сервера.

Comment: как определить пустой JSONObject?

Comment: можно длину проверить

Comment: например....